# wpf: how to let a geometry reduce just one pixel

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

for example:i have the red path(actually may be complex),how to dynamically get blue path just reduce one pixel?
[image]

Comment: Please don't just post pictures of markup or code. Post it as text.

Comment: Do you know the height and width of the real paths?  Because if you know you want something smaller than 49px width you can set width 48px on a path. And set stretch uniform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use two Paths with the same Data and let one be clipped by the Geometry in its Data:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Geometry x:Key="PathGeometry">M0,20 L12,0 34,0 46,20 34,40 12,40Z</Geometry>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid Margin="10">
    <Path Data="{StaticResource PathGeometry}" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="4"/>
    <Path Data="{StaticResource PathGeometry}" Stroke="Blue" StrokeThickness="4"
          Clip="{StaticResource PathGeometry}"/>
</Grid>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: that is what i want,simple and smart,thank you!!!